# after submitting the values in the database table are not updated

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, mysqli

I am new to PHP. When I am trying to update or modify my form then it is not getting updated in the phpmyadmin database table. I am using AJAX, jQuery, and PHP. I am badly stuck here so can anyone guide me that how to solve this issue. Thanks in advance. Following are the codes guys.

update_details.php

```
<div class="panel-body">
                        <?php 
                            $q1="SELECT * FROM `plantation_journal_basic_details` WHERE `plantation_journal_no`='$plantation_journal_no' ";
                            $r1=mysqli_query($con,$q1);
                            $ro1=mysqli_fetch_array($r1);
                         ?>
                        <form id="form1" action="update_details.php?id='<?php echo $plantation_journal_no; ?>'" name="form1" method="post">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <h4 style="font-size: 16px;"><b>Basic Details:</b></h4><br>
                                <div  align="right" style="padding-right: 10px;" >
                                    <div  align="right" style="padding-right: 10px;" >
                                    <label style="font-weight:300;font-size: 15px">Scheme:</label>
                                    <label align="left" style="width:50%;margin-left: 10px;font-weight:300;font-size: 15px"><?php echo $ro1['scheme']; ?></label><br><br>
                                    <label style="font-weight:300;font-size: 15px">Year:</label>
                                    <label align="left" style="width:50%;margin-left: 10px;font-weight:300;font-size: 15px"><?php echo $ro1['year']; ?></label><br><br>
                                    <label style="font-weight:300;font-size: 15px">Range:</label>
                                    <label align="left" style="width:50%;margin-left: 10px;font-weight:300;font-size: 15px"><?php echo $ro1['ranges']; ?></label><br><br>
                                    <label style="font-weight:300;font-size: 15px">Beat:</label>
                                    <label align="left" style="width:50%;margin-left: 10px;font-weight:300;font-size: 15px"><?php echo $ro1['beat']; ?></label><br><br>
                                    <label style="font-weight:300;font-size: 15px">JFMC:</label>
                                    <label align="left" style="width:50%;margin-left: 10px;font-weight:300;font-size: 15px"><?php echo $ro1['jfmc']; ?></label><br><br>
                                    <label style="font-weight:300;font-size: 15px">Panchayat Samity:</label>
                                    <label align="left" style="width:50%;margin-left: 10px;font-weight:300;font-size: 15px"><?php echo $ro1['panchayat_samity']; ?></label><br><br>
                                    <label style="font-weight:300;font-size: 15px">Gram Panchayat:</label>
                                    <label align="left" style="width:50%;margin-left: 10px;font-weight:300;font-size: 15px"><?php echo $ro1['gram_panchayat']; ?></label><br><br>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <h4 style="font-size: 16px;"><b>GPS Coordinates:</b></h4><br>
                                <div  align="right" style="padding-right: 10px;" >
                                    <label style="font-weight:300;font-size: 15px">Latitude:</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="latitude_degree" value="<?php echo $ro1['latitude_degree']; ?>"  style="width:10%;height: 30px; margin-left: 10px; border-radius: 5px; padding: 0 0 0 1px;">
                                    <label style="font-weight:300;font-size: 15px">°</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="latitude_minute" value="<?php echo $ro1['latitude_minute']; ?>"  style="width:10%;height: 30px; margin-left: 10px;  padding: 0 0 0 1px; border-radius: 5px;">
                                    <label style="font-weight:300;font-size: 15px">'</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="latitude_second" value="<?php echo $ro1['latitude_second']; ?>"  style="width:10%;height: 30px; margin-left: 10px; border-radius: 5px;  padding: 0 0 0 1px;">
                                    <label style="font-weight:300;font-size: 15px">"</label><br>
                                    <label style="font-weight:300;font-size: 15px">Longitude:</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="longitude_degree" value="<?php echo $ro1['longitude_degree']; ?>"  style="width:10%;height: 30px; margin-left: 10px; border-radius: 5px; padding: 0 0 0 1px;">
                                    <label style="font-weight:300;font-size: 15px">°</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="longitude_minute"  value="<?php echo $ro1['longitude_minute']; ?>" style="width:10%;height: 30px; margin-left: 10px; border-radius: 5px; padding: 0 0 0 1px;">
                                    <label style="font-weight:300;font-size: 15px">'</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="longitude_second" value="<?php echo $ro1['longitude_second']; ?>"  style="width:10%;height: 30px; margin-left: 10px; border-radius: 5px; padding: 0 0 0 1px;">
                                    <label style="font-weight:300;font-size: 15px">"</label><br>
                                </div>
                                <h4 style="font-size: 16px;"><b>Boundary:</b></h4><br>
                                <div  align="right" style="padding-right: 10px;" >
                                    <label style="font-weight:300;font-size: 15px">North:</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="north" value="<?php echo $ro1['north']; ?>"  style="width:50%;height: 30px; margin-left: 10px; border-radius: 5px;"><br>
                                    <label style="font-weight:300;font-size: 15px">East:</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="east" value="<?php echo $ro1['east']; ?>" style="width:50%;height: 30px; margin-left: 10px; border-radius: 5px;"><br>
                                    <label style="font-weight:300;font-size: 15px">West:</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="west" value="<?php echo $ro1['west']; ?>" style="width:50%;height: 30px; margin-left: 10px; border-radius: 5px;"><br>
                                    <label style="font-weight:300;font-size: 15px">South:</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="south" value="<?php echo $ro1['south']; ?>"  style="width:50%;height: 30px; margin-left: 10px; border-radius: 5px;"><br>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <h4 style="font-size: 16px;"><b>Surveyed By:</b></h4><br>
                                <div  align="right" style="padding-right: 10px;" >
                                    <label style="font-weight:300;font-size: 15px">Full Name:</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="full_name_s" value="<?php echo $ro1['ful_name_s']; ?>"  style="width:50%;height: 30px; margin-left: 10px; border-radius: 5px;"><br>
                                    <label style="font-weight:300;font-size: 15px">Designation:</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="designation_s" value="<?php echo $ro1['designation_s']; ?>"  style="width:50%;height: 30px; margin-left: 10px; border-radius: 5px;"><br>
                                </div>
                                <h4 style="font-size: 16px;"><b>Checked By:</b></h4><br>
                                <div  align="right" style="padding-right: 10px;" >
                                    <label style="font-weight:300;font-size: 15px">Full Name:</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="full_name_c"  value="<?php echo $ro1['full_name_c']; ?>" style="width:50%;height: 30px; margin-left: 10px; border-radius: 5px;"><br>
                                    <label style="font-weight:300;font-size: 15px">Designation:</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="designation_c"  value="<?php echo $ro1['designation_c']; ?>" style="width:50%;height: 30px; margin-left: 10px; border-radius: 5px;"><br>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div align="right">
                            <input class="btn btn-info btn-submit8" type="submit" name="submit_1" value="Add" onclick="move1()">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <?php 
                            if(isset($_POST['latitude_degree'])){
                            $latitude_degree=$_POST['latitude_degree'];
                            $latitude_minute=$_POST['latitude_minute'];
                            $latitude_second=$_POST['latitude_second'];
                            $longitude_degree=$_POST['longitude_degree'];
                            $longitude_minute=$_POST['longitude_minute'];
                            $longitude_second=$_POST['longitude_second'];
                            $north=$_POST['north'];
                            $east=$_POST['east'];
                            $west=$_POST['west'];
                            $south=$_POST['south'];
                            $full_name_s=$_POST['full_name_s'];
                            $designation_s=$_POST['designation_s'];
                            $full_name_c=$_POST['full_name_c'];
                            $designation_c=$_POST['designation_c'];
                            $sql="UPDATE `plantation_journal_basic_details` SET `latitude_degree`='$latitude_degree',`latitude_minute`='$latitude_minute',`latitude_second`='$latitude_second',`longitude_degree`='$longitude_degree',`longitude_minute`='$longitude_minute',`longitude_second`='$longitude_second',`north`='$north',`east`='$east',`west`='$west',`south`='$south',`ful_name_s`='$full_name_s',`designation_s`='$designation_s',`full_name_c`='$full_name_c',`designation_c`='$designation_c' WHERE `plantation_journal_no`='$plantation_journal_no'";

                            $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                            }
                         ?>
```

Comment: See about prepared and bound queries. Also, I'm not convinced that storing degrees, minutes, and seconds as separate entities is a good idea

Comment: @Strawberry That doesn't solve anything

Comment: I think the problem is `url: "update_details.php?id='$plantation_journal_no'"`. Try with `url: "update_details.php?id='<?php echo $plantation_journal_no; ?>'"`

Comment: If you do a var_dump on $_POST, what do you get?

Comment: @EmptyBrain I am getting this error Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\fdwb\update_details.php on line 281

Comment: Because your `$r1` is empty @SnehaRoy

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to submit all your input values is with:

```
$('#form').ajaxForm({
    /*....*/
});
```

Did you try it?